# Sort a numpy-array according to specific column

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

Consider a numpy array such as the following:

```
  coords =   [[34. 22.]
              [11. 38.]
              [22. 56.]
              [23. 22.]
              [86. 30.]]
```

This array contains the x- and y-coordinates of 5 points. I am looking for the point within this array that has the smallest y-coordinate. I can easily find it using

```
idx = np.argpartition(coords[:,1],1)[0]
pt = coords[idx]
```

No problem. Except that there are actually two points in `coords` which have the same smallest y-value: 22

I want the point that has the smaller x-value, i.e. instead of `[34 22]` I want `[23 22]`.

This is no longer trivial. Because I want to be able to find such points for an arbitrary coords matrix. I.e. there could be many points with an equal smallest y-coord. More than just two. And then I want to sort these according to their x-coord.

I was starting to solve this with an ugly for-loop, but failed. This is what I have so far:

```
noPoints = coords.shape[0]

y = []
for i in range(0, noPoints-1):
    minIdx = 0
    for j in range(i+1, noPoints):
        if coords[j][1] < coords[i][1]:
            minIdx = j
```

Well. I can find the smallest y-value. But that's it. I'm starting to believe this task cannot be solved with numpy-arrays.

Comment: Can you provide `coords` with valid syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with *structured* numpy array and the `order=` optional keyword in [numpy's sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html):

```
>>> x = np.array([(34.,22.),(11., 38.),(22.,56.),(23., 22.),(86.,30.)], dtype = [('x',float),('y',float)])
>>> x
array([(34., 22.), (11., 38.), (22., 56.), (23., 22.), (86., 30.)],
  dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
>>> x.sort(order = ['y','x'])
>>> x
array([(23., 22.), (34., 22.), (86., 30.), (11., 38.), (22., 56.)],
  dtype=[('x', '<f8'), ('y', '<f8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [np.lexsort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
coords[np.lexsort((coords[:,1], coords[:,0]))]
```

output:

```
array([[11., 38.],
       [22., 56.],
       [23., 22.],
       [34., 22.],
       [86., 30.]])
```